# Grunt task for uploading a file to CouchDB using request

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, couchdb

In my `Gruntfile.coffee`, I have set up a task:

```
grunt.registerTask 'couch_upload', 'CouchDB upload', ->
  done = @async()

  assets = ['combined.min.js', 'screen.min.css']
  ddoc = 'http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/app'
  request = require 'request'
  fs = require 'fs'
  grunt.log.writeln 'Uploading assets...'

  upload = (asset) ->
    # get the revision of the design document
    request.get {json: yes, url: ddoc}, (err, resp, body) ->
      rev = body._rev
      # stream the file and pipe it, so it has the correct Content-Type
      fs.createReadStream('build/' + asset).pipe request.put
        auth: user: 'myusername', password: 'mypass'
        headers: 'If-Match': rev
        url: [ddoc, asset].join '/'
      , -> grunt.log.write ' ' + asset

  upload asset for asset in assets

  done()
```

but I cannot see anything uploaded, neither on Grunt's log, nor Couch's log.

Can you tell if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to open a feature request to CouchDB-Lucene: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/issues — it doesn’t look like it has that feature enabled yet, if it is at all possible.

Comment: I appreciate your effort at answering, but Lucene has no part in this. CouchDB supports attachment uploads just fine. This is some kind of asynch issue; some/all of these happen: 1) Second file reports 409 (doc conflict), 2) fs piping overwrites all other headers (like auth and If-Match) 3) JSON.strigify mixes up the order with multipart/related. I can make it work with just one file, but not multiple. Even if in different tasks.

Comment: I meant to post this on a different question, ignore me. Sorry! :D